# How do I extract the colors from an image, like in this example

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, pixel

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement something like this in c#. How do I extract the colors from the image?

**Edit**
I'm trying to accomplish something like this:
[image]

Comment: "Most intensive" needs to be formally defined. A metric is needed. This could be quite hard, because color-perception is non-uniform [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).

Comment: Well, let me adjust my question. I just came up with something that should explain better what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: well you could blur the whole image at lets say 120% size in a what looks to be an oval shape and fade the edge to black., and then superimpose the original image in the almost center of the blur (looks like its alittlebit below center. Thats what i would have tried first.

Comment: Do you want list of color?

Comment: yes, I would like the rgb values of the colors projected at the TV borders.